# What should I do if there are two duplicate close votes that I think are wrong, and the question is not clear?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

I just voted to close [How can I get the input argument of a function being called in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883682). The question doesn't really make any sense at all, so I voted to close the question as unclear. Unfortunately (?) for me, there were already two close votes as a duplicate of a question about command-line arguments.

I can't tell for sure what the question is *actually* trying to ask - my best *guess* is that it is something about mocking code for a test framework. But I *am* sure that it is *not* about command-line arguments, like the given duplicate. I am pretty confident that it is not a duplicate of anything, because it isn't clear enough to identify a duplicate.

Did I do the right thing by adding a third vote anyway, allowing the question to be closed, and trying to explain in the comments?

Comment: Unclear questions being closed, is a good thing, ultimately the question can be reopened provided the question is made clear so the close reason ultimately isn’t that important

Comment: Please note that any question could have multiple valid close reasons at once. Too broad questions are almost per definition also unclear. Questions lacking reproducible code are unclear. A question asking which is the best tool is both a recommendation question and primarily opinion-based. Any problematic question for whatever reason, could also be a duplicate. And so on. The important thing is that the question gets closed, the reason why is secondary. Though in case there are multiple problems it's always nice to the OP know that through comments.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you did the right thing.

It is a problem with unclear questions - some read it one way (and are 100% sure what is asked), others read something different (and again are 100% sure what is asked), and the rest are confused what the question even asks. Which is reflected in the current votes - duplicate*2, unclear, gold-badge-reopen, unclear.

Should you do something immediately after the question is closed - probably no. We don't re-open questions that *you think* should be closed, even if the close reason is not ideal. In this case, the author is expected to clarify the question in either case of duplicate or unclear closure - so there is not much impact on the author of the question either.

A couple of things to consider are to "follow" the question and potentially vote if it is edited later and possibly edit list of duplicates (if you have the gold badge).

Comment: Agreed you shouldn't reopen, but you can *comment* to explain that you think the duplicate isn't helpful, but that there are problems with the question which need to be fixed.

Comment: It reminds me of the classic trivia team name, "Often Wrong, But Never In Doubt"