# How to vote to close as a "duplicate" after votes for "needs details/clarity" are no longer relevant?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions

Here's the question that gives more context: [internet connectivity status with react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145825/internet-connectivity-status-with-react-js). The question was first asked without including any relevant code (see [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77145825/1)). Later, code is added (see [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77145825/4)). Before the code was added, the question attracted 2 close votes for, assuming, "needs details or clarity". As I believed the question was a duplicate of [Detect if the internet connection is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-if-the-internet-connection-is-offline), I voted to close as a duplicate. As 3 close votes were earned, the question was closed. However the close reason is not accurate. I've left a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145825/internet-connectivity-status-with-react-js#comment136011136_77145825) explaining this.

My questions are:

- Was this approach correct? If not, what is the alternative?
- How can such a scenario where *no longer relevant vote closures influence the closure too much* be avoided?<sup>*</sup>
- Can the close reason be fixed?

<sub>Wasn't sure how to phrase this but I hope you get the idea.</sub>

Comment: You pretty much did the correct thing, now just let the wrong close reason go: [Should we allow voting to change the close vote reason of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262761/should-we-allow-voting-to-change-the-close-vote-reason-of-a-question)

Comment: Fixing the close reason is icky. Unless mods get involved, the community can vote to reopen and then vote to close again with the corrected reason. As for the mods, I don't know if they can or can't but you can't always expect the mod handling whatever ticket you raise to understand the technology well enough to be qualified to agree with you. Generally leaving the question closed and leaving a comment is the best option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do if there are two duplicate close votes that I think are wrong, and the question is not clear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420590/what-should-i-do-if-there-are-two-duplicate-close-votes-that-i-think-are-wrong) (My situation was the other way around, but I think the same logic applies.)